# "warning: can't perform a react state update on an unmounted component " But none of the methods work

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is my code, I tried bunch of methods but I don't know how to make them work properly :/
I appreciate any kind of help!

```js
const fetchData = React.useCallback(() => {
  fetch('http://5sd780beaf65.ngrok.io/api/Data')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => {
      setData(responseJson);
      setFullData(responseJson.results);
      setLoading(false);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      setLoading(false);
      setError(err);
    });
}, []);

React.useEffect(() => {
  let isMounted = true;
  fetchData();
}, [fetchData]);
```

Comment: Please give more context on what is the desired behavior and what is happening instead.

Comment: I want to not have “warning: can't perform a react state update on an unmounted component ” but i keep having it no matter what i try

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue of using `useCallback` and not including certain methods internal to your component in the dependency array.  For example, you're using what sounds like `setState` methods in your callback (`setData`, `setFullData`, etc.), which I'm guessing are setState methods on the component in question.  If something is causing the component to rerender, those methods are reinitialized, and the reference to `setFullData` (and the *component* it references) change on rerender.  But because you've used `useCallback`, a newly rerendered component is calling setState methods that belong to a component instance that is stale / no longer mounted.

Solutions: either don't use `useCallback`, or include all relevant variables and methods in the dependency array:

```js
const fetchData = React.useCallback(() => {
  fetch("http://5sd780beaf65.ngrok.io/api/Data")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      setData(responseJson);
      setFullData(responseJson.results);
      setLoading(false);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      setLoading(false);
      setError(err);
    });
  }, [setData, setFullData, setLoading, setError]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your fetchData function asynchronous then add a await before fetch